# How can I import my BibTeX file to my Google Scholar Library?

Tags: citations, google-scholar

I have a large library of articles in CiteULike, but recently it does not work very well, so I would like to move to using the Google Scholar library. I exported my CiteULike library to a BibTeX file. Is there a way to import this file to my Google Scholar library?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, currently you cannot...